# Shareable List of Links With Notifications

Tags: android, web-apps, ios, web-services, distributed

So basically I am creating *Tinycards* decks for the vocabulary of each *Duolingo* Hebrew level that feature transliterations to practice learning not only the words and their meanings but also their pronunciations. Once I have created a new deck I need to share its link with our club so that when they reach that level they can practice the pronunciation of the words for that level because Duolingo lacks such a dedicated feature.

Now I know there are plenty of ways to do this. I can, for example, create a mailing list and distribute the links via email. But this method seems very inefficient and outdated for me and means that I will have to send all the links whenever a new member joins our club.

So what I am looking for is a *mobile* (compulsory) and *web* (optional) application or service with which I can create a *list* or a *folder* wherein I can add the links and also give them proper names. I then want to be able to share the list or folder in such a manner that whenever I create a new deck and add its link, everyone must be notified of the newly added link.

Can anyone think of an application or service that supports this sort of functionality and features?

Comment: Are you OK with *maintaining* the list with a desktop computer rather than with mobile?

Comment: Once you post a link, will it stay the same forever? Or will you want to fix the title of the before-last link, for instance? Or even insert a new link *between* two existing links?

Comment: Hi @NicolasRaoul. Yes, maintaining the list with a desktop shouldn’t be an issue. As for the links staying the same forever, probably not no. I would like the ability to change them, sort them A-Z or Z-A, etc.

Comment: I was thinking of a RSS feed, since there are RSS clients for any platform, with notifications. But with RSS you are not really supposed to modify past information, and clients might not update past entries. Do you want notifications each time you fix a typo or change the order?